# Strapi Cron tasks not running

Tags: node.js, cron, nodemailer, strapi

i don't notice cron tasks on my server (I have also enabled cron task on the server.js file)

This is what my cron task looks like

```
"*/1 * * * *": () => {
    console.log("month");
  },
```

It is supposed to run every minute

Answer (score 1):

You will need to be sure to set up two things in strapi.

1. your con.js inside config/functions/cron.js

```
module.exports = {
//...
  '0/10 * * * * *': () => {
    console.log("I am running every 10 seconds >> " + new Date());
  },
//..
};
```

2. add the following to your config/server.js to enable the process

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  //...
  cron: {
    enabled: true
  },
  //...
});
```

LOG
[image]

Comment: Did you try ` yarn build --clean && yarn develop`